# Swift Popover presentation get ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

If I have `ViewController1` and do a Popover Presentation to `ViewController2`. How I can call methods of `ViewController1` in `ViewController2`?

Comment: There are lots of posts that answer this question already. Did you search first before asking? What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a child view controller needs to call methods on its parent you might want to reconsider the design and investigate whether you can refactor- normally a view controller should be essentially self-contained and a child shouldn't need to know about its parent.

However, you can accomplish this by implementing `prepareForSegue(segue, sender)` in the parent view controller and setting appropriate properties on the child (accessed via `segue.destinationViewController`).